# Does Newman's network modularity work for signed, weighted graphs?

Tags: clustering, data-visualization, networks, partitioning, modularity

The modularity of a graph is defined on its [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_%28networks%29). In a [different post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/how-to-do-community-detection-in-a-weighted-social-network-graph), somebody explained that modularity can easily be computed (and maximized) for weighted networks because the adjacency matrix $A_{ij}$ can as well contain valued ties. However, I would like to know whether this would also work with signed, valued edges, ranging, for instance, from -10 to +10. Can you provide an intuition, proof or reference on this issue?

Answer (score 14):

The *straightforward* generalization of the modularity for weighted networks does *not* work if those weights are signed. By straightforward, I mean: just using the weight matrix instead of the adjacency one, like Newman does, for instance, in [(Newman 2004)](http://pre.aps.org/abstract/PRE/v70/i5/e056131). You need a specific version, such as that cited by BenjaminLind, or that of [(Gomez et al. 2009)](http://deim.urv.cat/~aarenas/publicacions/pdf/signed.pdf).

In both articles, they explain the reason for this. In summary: the modularity relies on the fact some normalized degrees (or strengths in the case of weighted networks) can be considered as probabilities. The probability a link exists between nodes $i$ and $j$ is estimated using $p_ip_j=w_iw_j/(2w)^2$, where $w_i$ and $w_j$ are the respective strengths of nodes $i$ and $j$ and $w$ is the total strength over all the network nodes. If some weights are negative, then the original normalization doesn't guarantee having values in $[0,1]$ anymore, so the above $p_ip_j$ quantity cannot be considered as a probability.

To solve this problem, Gomez *et al*. consider positive and negative links separately. They obtain two distinct modularity values: one for positive links, one for negative ones. They substract the latter from the former to get the overall modularity.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I will take a look at the Gomez et al. article. Is there an implementation?

Comment: Yes, I think you'll find the source code here: http://deim.urv.cat/~sgomez/radatools.php

Comment: the code looks blackboxed to EXE files, but if all you need is modularity for positive and negative weights, why not just (1) convert your matrix to a weighted edge list, (2) split the list between positively and negatively signed weights, and (3) compute modularity with `igraph` using absolute weights in each partition?

Comment: That's a good idea, but the modularity processed for negative weights must be minimized, and the methods in igraph only do maximization (as far as I know). As for the source code, I think you're right. Maybe you can contact directly one of the authors?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it can. Spin-glass models for community detection can compute modularity from weighted, signed graphs. You'll want Traag and Bruggeman ["Community detection in networks with positive and negative links"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2329) as a reference. The function ["spinglass.community()"](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/spinglass.community.html) in igraph can find the communities and return the graph's modularity.

Comment: Thank you. I am not really interested in the communities but rather in the tendency of the signed network to be polarized/fragmented into communities. But as far as I can see, the modularity can be retrieved from the resulting ``communities`` object using the ``modularity`` function. I will definitely take a look at the Traag and Bruggeman article. Since the implementation seems to be based on simulated annealing: how well does it perform? Can I actually make sure that the algorithm really returns the _optimal_ modularity (since I want to measure polarization/fragmentation)?

Answer (score 3):

We have pointed out the problem of Modularity[-alike] functions with signed networks [in this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep14339). They tend to ignore the positive density of communities more as the absolute number of negative links in the network increases.

Also, here is our [open source java project](https://github.com/pouyaesm/signed-community-detection) for weighted-signed networks, which is based on [Constant Potts Model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.3083) (similar to Modularity), fast [Louvain algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0476), and community evaluation based on an extension of [Map Equation](http://www.pnas.org/content/105/4/1118).

[Esmailian, P. and Jalili, M., 2015. Community detection in signed networks: the role of negative ties in different scales. Scientific reports, 5, p.14339](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep14339)